# promises in javascript confusion

Tags: javascript, promise

Why does my code **sometimes** prints `"C"` before `"A"`?

```js
function printstring(string) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.write(string);
      resolve();
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  })
}

function printall() {
  printstring("A")
    .then(printstring("C"))
}

printall();
```

Comment: This is a typo, use a linter with proper rules or a promise library that gives you warnings for this like bluebird.

Answer (score 4):

`then` expects a callback. This callback is called, and is passed the resolved value of the promise as the parameter.

In your code, you've provided `printstring('C')` as callback. So the result of `printstring('C')`, which is again a promise will be executed with the response. Since you've used a random timeout for execution, the order of printing on the document will depend on it. If the timeout of printing C expires before the timeout of printing A, C will definitely be printed first.

To correct this, use an anonymous function as a `then` callback, i.e. convert this:

```
.then(printstring("C"))
```

to this:

```
.then(() => printstring("C"))
```

See the following working demo:

```js
function printstring(string) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.write(string);
      resolve();
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  })
}

function printall() {
  printstring("A")
    .then(() => printstring("C"))
}

printall();
```

Comment: But the callback i.e. resolve should not be called until i have printed A. @31pjy

Comment: @FauadHaleem -- The point is that `printstring("C")` is called first and its result is passed as a callback. It will not care whether the promise is resolved or not.

Answer (score 4):

```
 printstring("A")
   .then(printstring("C"))
```

Is equal to:

```
const promise1 = printstring("A");
const promise2 = printstring("C");

 promise1.then(promise2)
```

So basically you start both actions at the same time, not one after the other. Passing a promise as a callback doesnt really make sense. Instead you may want to wait for the first promise to resolve before starting the next action:

```
printstring("A").then(function() {
  printstring("C");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with promises, I believe.

Whenever you write a code like this -

```
function mainFn(callback) {
    // do async stuff
    // call callback when done
    callback();
}

// callback handler
function callbackFn() {
    console.log('callback fn');
}
```

You need to make sure that you pass callback function's reference to the callback parameter of `mainFn()`, like so -

```
// Passess reference to callback function inside mainFn
mainFn(callbackFn);
```

However, doing something like -

```
// Executes the callback function and passes it's result into mainFn
mainFn(callbackFn());
```

is totally wrong. This is similar to what you're doing with `.then(printstring("C"))`. It will execute `printstring("C")` first.

So, to deal with this, wrap it in an anonymous function like so -

```
 function printall() {
  printstring("A")
    .then(function() { printstring("C"); })
 }
```